# Merge ou combine Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de combinar dois `arrays` (`$a` e `$b`) de forma que ficasse assim `$c = $a[0]$b[0],$a[1]$b[1]...$a[n]$b[n]` como proceder existe uma função tentei fazer com `foreach` mas sem sucesso.

```
$array1 = array("laranja", "morango");
$array2 = array("s1", "s2");
$result = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

No caso gostaria como resultado:

```
['laranja', 's1', 'morango', 's2']
```

Comment: Você quer o resultado desta forma? "laranja", "s1", "morango", "s2"?

Comment: isso mesmo desta forma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$array1 = array("laranja", "morango");
$array2 = array("s1", "s2");

$new = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++) {
   $new[] = $array1[$i];
   $new[] = $array2[$i];
}
var_export($new);
```

Ou

```
$array1 = array("laranja", "morango");
$array2 = array("s1", "s2");

$result = array();
array_map(function ($a, $b) use (&$result) { array_push($result, $a, $b); }, $array1, $array2);
var_export($result);
```

Resultado:

> array ( 0 => 'laranja', 1 => 's1', 2 => 'morango', 3 => 's2', )

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638953/merge-two-arrays-alternatively)

Comment: Obrigado, perfeito !!